# scanf without newline (C programming)

Tags: c, scanf, newline, enter, hit

I dont want to newline after scanf.

```
printf("I am  ");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf(" years old");
```

This output is;

```
 I am 19
years old.
```

But i want to like this:

```
I am 19 years old.
```

Comment: which compiler you are using

Comment: visual studio 2017

Comment: Please visit both of these link, you will an idea how to proceed

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170021/how-could-i-achieve-gotoxy-in-gcc

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706439/gotoxy-function-is-not-working-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using scanf() properly. The function scanf() takes in user input and then stores it in a variable, and in your case that would be the variable 'age'. After that you can place the variable age in the printf() statement like this.

```
scanf("%d", &age);
printf("I am %d years old.", age);
```

That code will first wait for the user to enter an age then it would print the sentence:

> I am X years old.

The reason your screen is displaying your output on two lines is because the, "scanf("%d", &age);" requires you to hit enter after you type in a number (which creates a new line) in order for "printf(" years old");" to execute. Also, when you are hitting enter in your code, the number being stored in the variable 'age' isn't doing anything. You're just storing it for no reason.